# How to pick Max value of SQL Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Query Syntax issue. I have a query which returns around 150,000 rows of records. In this query, you can see `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION`. On `select * from cte`, I need to pick only the highest value of `ROW_NUMBER()` for each Pat_id.

If RowNumber is 150 for one pat_id. I need only that row of records. I am having difficult in narrowing down to one record. I request experts to share your syntax to help me.

```
with cte
as (
    select  pat.pat_id,
            pat.fname as [FirstName],
            pat.mname as [MiddleName],
            pat.lname as [LastName],
            [DOB] =Convert(VARCHAR(12),pat.birth_date,101),
            csc.name as [AccountType],
            [Plan Name] = CASE when (isnull(org.name,'')='') then 'CASH' else org.name end
            ,cprx_disp.disp_days_supply
            ,cprx_disp.dispense_date
            ,(cprx_disp.dispense_date + cprx_disp.disp_days_supply) as [DateDue]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY  pat.pat_id ORDER BY cprx_disp.dispense_date) as [RowNumber]

    From    cppat pat (nolock)
            left outer join cppat_ins patins(NoLock) ON patins.pat_id = pat.pat_id
            left outer join csorg org on org.org_id = patins.org_id
            inner join csct_code csc on pat.pat_type_cn = csc.code_num
            join cprx on cprx.pat_id = pat.pat_id
            join cprx_disp (nolock) on cprx.last_rxdisp_id =  cprx_disp.rxdisp_id

    where   csc.ct_id = 163
            and csc.code_num in (1033,1010,1011,1012,1016,1017,1016,1018)
            and patins.status_cn = 1
            and patins.priority = 1

    --   Commented. 
    -- and pat.pat_id = 2561
)
select  cte.[FirstName],
        cte.[MiddleName],
        cte.[LastName],
        cte.[DOB],  
        cte.[AccountType],
        cte.[Plan Name],
        Cte.DateDue

from cte
```

Comment: Use select top 1 from cte

Comment: ... and `order by rownumber desc`

Comment: or even if he needs 150 then where cte.rownumber = 150

Comment: Top 1 from cte and order by rownumber desc helps. But

Comment: @Joe, i just edited the query. Please share your syntax

Comment: This query returns around 2000 unique Pat_Id's and each id has around 100's of rownumber. In the end , i need to return only 2000 unique Pat_Id's with their max rownumber

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just `SELECT MAX(RowNumber), Pat_ID FROM cte Group by Pat_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're not actually using the `RowNumber` in the output, so I would just reverse it and then return those that equal 1:

```
with cte
as (
    select  pat.pat_id,
            pat.fname as [FirstName],
            pat.mname as [MiddleName],
            pat.lname as [LastName],
            [DOB] =Convert(VARCHAR(12),pat.birth_date,101),  
            csc.name as [AccountType],
            [Plan Name] = CASE when (isnull(org.name,'')='') then 'CASH' else org.name end
            ,cprx_disp.disp_days_supply
            ,cprx_disp.dispense_date
            ,(cprx_disp.dispense_date + cprx_disp.disp_days_supply) as [DateDue]        
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY  pat.pat_id ORDER BY cprx_disp.dispense_date DESC) as [RowNumber]   

    from    cppat pat (nolock) 
            left outer join cppat_ins patins(NoLock) on patins.pat_id = pat.pat_id
            left outer join csorg org on org.org_id = patins.org_id
            inner join csct_code csc on pat.pat_type_cn = csc.code_num
            join cprx on cprx.pat_id = pat.pat_id 
            join cprx_disp (nolock) on cprx.last_rxdisp_id =  cprx_disp.rxdisp_id     
    where   csc.ct_id = 163
            and csc.code_num in (1033,1010,1011,1012,1016,1017,1016,1018)
            and patins.status_cn = 1
            and patins.priority = 1

    --   Commented. 
    -- and pat.pat_id = 2561
)
select  cte.[FirstName],
        cte.[MiddleName],
        cte.[LastName],
        cte.[DOB],  
        cte.[AccountType],
        cte.[Plan Name],
        cte.DateDue

from    cte
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```